# Nuxtjs Vue-session - Cannot read property 'exits' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to support `Vue-session` in `Nuxt.js`.

I already make a website using `Vue.js` but it's not good for `SEO`.

So, I make a new front-end using `Nuxt.js`. 
I copy some components from directory `Vue.js` to `Nuxt.js` and run.

But it's not working. I received an error in my `Header.vue` - Login. Here's my code.

TypeError

Cannot read property 'exits' of undefined

```
https://imgur.com/a/hkccHvL
```

In Header,vue there is the code here please check it out.

```
<template>
      <b-navbar sticky toggleable="md" class="navbar-dark bd-navbar" type="dark">
        <b-navbar-toggle target="bd-main-nav" />
        <b-navbar-brand to="/">My Blog</b-navbar-brand>
        <b-collapse
          is-nav
          class="justify-content-between"
          id="bd-main-nav">
          <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
          <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
            <b-nav-item v-if="this.isLoggedIn==true">     
              <span v-show="userName.length > 0" class="align-middle ml-2 text-color">
                {{userName}}
              </span>
              <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0 btn-outline-light btn-space" @click="clickToSignOut">
                Sign out
              </b-button>
            </b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item v-else>
              <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0 btn-outline-light" 
                @click="this.clickToLogin"
                >Login
              </b-button>
            </b-nav-item>   
          </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-collapse>
      </b-navbar>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'Header',
        data() {
          return {
            userName:'',
            profileUrl:'',
            isLoggedIn: false
          }
        },
        created() {
          if (this.$session.exits()) {
            let userObject = this.$session.get('loggedInUser')
            this.userName = userObject.name ? userObject.name : ''
            this.profileUrl = userObject.profileUrl ? userObject.profileUrl : ''
            this.isLoggedIn = userObject ? true : false
          } else {
            this.userName = ""
            this.profileUrl = ""
            this.isLoggedIn = false
          }
        },
        methods: {
          clickToLogin() {
            // this.$emit('clickToLogin')
            this.$router.push("Login")
          },
          clickToSignOut() {         
            this.userName = ''
            this.profileUrl = ''
            this.isLoggedIn = false           
            // this.$emit('clickToSignOut')   
            this.$session.destroy()
            this.$router.push('/')
          }, 
        }
    }
```

In nuxt.config.js

```
    const pkg = require('./package')


    module.exports = {
      mode: 'universal',
      head: {
        title: pkg.name,
        meta: [
          { charset: 'utf-8' },
          { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
          { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
        ],
        link: [
          { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
        ],
      },
      loading: { color: '#fff' },
      css: [
      ],
      plugins: [
        '~/plugins/VueSession.js',
        '~/plugins/VeeValidate.js'
      ],
      modules: [,
        // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
      ],
      build: {
        extend(config, ctx) {
        }
      }
    }
```

here is the content of js part please look it out and give me the answer
plugins/VueSession.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSession from 'vue-session'
if (process.client) {
  Vue.use(VueSession)
}
```

Comment: your plugin is set to be applied only on client, but then you are trying to access it in created hook which is executed on server, so hance a error

Comment: thank you very much! How can I fix ít?

Comment: use mounted hook it executed only on client, or wrap your code in created with if process.client

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access VueSession inside created hook, which is fired in the server side, and Your plugin loads only in client side, thats why VueSession is undefined.

Either move the code from created () method to mounted (), as mounted () is executed only in client side, or add if (process.browser) check, to see if its client side.

Alternatively, use nuxt-session (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-session) which would be Nuxt.js equivalent to the Vue.js plugin.

Hope this helps, cheers!